# How to read unbuffered input of lines ending with "\r" or "\n"?

Tags: perl, io, stdin

I'm writing  a simple  program which  is intended  to filter
input from a  pipeline. Most of the input is  sent as output
untouched.  Part  of  it  is modified  or  used  to  extract
information.  In its  simplest form  — doing  nothing —  the
program `filter` is:

```
$|++;

while (<>) {
    print;
}
```

The main  program sometimes outputs progress  updates of its
task, overwriting the same visual content through the use of
lines ending with a carriage  return. Piping such content to
`filter` blocks all output:

```
$ perl -e '$|++; print ++$a, "\r" and sleep 1 while 1' | filter
```

Is there  an easy way to  read those lines in  the same loop
fashion, or should  I go the `sysread` way?  I'm looking for
something similar to what would happen if it was possible to
set the record separator to "`\n` *or* `\r`".

Comment: You can set the record separator using `$/`. Just set it to "\r" before the loop.

Comment: @beasy Sure, but then normal lines ending with "\n" will be held buffered up to the next "\r", right?

Comment: Oh you mean the input lines sometimes end in "\n", and sometimes "\r"?

Comment: @beasy Yes. As I mentioned, the _"program sometimes outputs progress updates of its task […] through the use of lines ending with a carriage return"_. My one line example outputs only `\r` lines just to demonstrate this technique, in case it's not clear or known.

Comment: The output with `\r` (and no newlines) is never a "line" so it's just not flushed? (That nice one-liner test doesn't print even when `\r` is removed).  So I think that the filter just doesn't get any data (until some other buffers get filled or a newline _is_ sent, of course).

Comment: So I'd say that if output of a program using `\r` is piped (into anything) only the last print will make it to the filter, once there is a line-feed?

Comment: [`Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp)

Comment: @zdim I'm not sure if I got it right, but the one-liner test should produce output since `$|++` turns on the auto flush for stdout. Well, at least here it does produce output (with or without `\r`). Output does seem to get to the filter program correctly, unbuffered. I.e., this works: 
`perl -e '$|++; print ++$a, "\r" and sleep 1 while 1' | perl -e '$|++; print getc while 1'`

Comment: @sidyll  Yes, apparently I misunderstood some bits about buffering (I'd think that `$|++` still needs LF), since `getc` clearly can get things from the stream.  Interesting question and answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the input isn't so large that efficiency is a concern, this version of `filter` is more robust

```
while (!eof(STDIN)) {
    $_ .= getc(STDIN);
    if (/[\r\n]/) {
        # manipulate $_, if desired
        print;
        $_ = "";
    }
}
print;
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent. The module you linked in the comments above is also phenomenal. I was disappointed to read the awk note in the documentation but not anymore :)